# Transforming XML basd on certain condtions using XSLT

Tags: xslt

Below is  my requirement.

1)  I want an element ‘error’ to be added as a last element in  based on certain condition evaluated to true.
2)  I want an element ‘generic_quote_ind’ to be added just after ‘quote_or_print’ element based on some other condition if gets evaluated to true.

Below is my input XML, XSLT that I have written and expected output XML.

Using this piece of code , I am able to add ‘error’ element as the last element in , but I am unable to add the ‘generic_quote_ind’ just after ‘quote_or_print’ element.

Please guide me on how can achieve this?

**Input XML**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<message xmlns="http://www.origoservices.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org /2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<m_control>
    <control_timestamp>2013-06-06T14:55:37</control_timestamp>
    <initiator_id>ASL</initiator_id>
</m_control>
<m_content>
    <b_control>
        <quote_type>Comparison</quote_type>
        <quote_or_print>Quote And Print</quote_or_print>
        <message_version_number>3.7</message_version_number>
</b_control>
  <application>
    <product>
        <tpsdata>
            <service_type>QuickQuote</service_type>
            <quote_type>Standard</quote_type>
        </tpsdata>
    </product>
</application>
</m_content>
</message>
```

**Expected OutPut**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message xmlns="http://www.origoservices.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<m_control>
    <control_timestamp>2013-06-06T14:55:37</control_timestamp>
    <initiator_id>ASL</initiator_id>
</m_control>
<m_content>
    <b_control>
        <quote_type>Comparison</quote_type>
        <quote_or_print>Quote And Print</quote_or_print>
        <generic_quote_ind>Yes</generic_quote_ind>
        <message_version_number>3.7</message_version_number>
    </b_control>
<application>
    <product>
        <tpsdata>
            <service_type>QuickQuote</service_type>
            <quote_type>Standard</quote_type>
        </tpsdata>
    </product>
</application>
</m_content>
</message>
```

**XSLT that I have tried**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"    xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath- functions" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="dp">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="*">
<!-- identity with closing tags -->
<xsl:element name="{name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:variable name="GenericQuoteInd">
<xsl:value-of select="/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local- name()='message']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='m_content']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='b_control']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='generic_quote_ind']"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="InitiatorId">
<xsl:value-of select="/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='message']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='m_control']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='initiator_id']"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="ServiceType">
<xsl:value-of select="/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='message']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='m_content']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='application']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='product']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='tpsdata']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='service_type']"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="quoteNPrint">
<xsl:value-of select="/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='message']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='m_content']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='b_control']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='quote_or_print']"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='message']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='m_content']/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.origoservices.com' and local-name()='b_control']">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="(($GenericQuoteInd = 'Yes') or (($InitiatorId = 'ASL') and   ($ServiceType='QuickQuote'))) and ($quoteNPrint='Quote And Print')">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:element name="error" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">can not provide quotation</xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="(($GenericQuoteInd = '') and (($InitiatorId = 'ASL') and ($ServiceType='QuickQuote'))) and ($quoteNPrint='QuoteOnly')">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:element name="generic_quote_ind" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">Yes</xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="($GenericQuoteInd = 'Yes') and ($quoteNPrint='QuoteOnly')">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:when>
<!--xsl:when test="($GenericQuoteInd = ' Yes') or (($InitiatorId = 'ASL') and ($ServiceType='QuickQuote')) and ($quoteNPrint='QuoteOnly')">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:when-->
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    <xsl:element name="otherwise_loop" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">Yes</xsl:element>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*|comment()|processing-instruction()">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*|namespace::*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please show what you have attempted thus far.

Comment: Hello I have  updated my question with the XSLT that tried so far.

Comment: Good ... can you show the desired output, and the actual output? Also, can you show more of the input XML? A critical part of it is missing, the `<message>` open tag that may have a default namespace declaration on it.

Comment: FYI, you can save a lot of trouble by declaring the origoservices namespace on the `<xsl:stylesheet>` element: `xmlns:origo="http://www.origoservices.com"`, and using that prefix instead of predicates about namespace-uri and local-name: `<xsl:value-of select="/origo:message/origo:m_content/..." />`.

Comment: Never mind about the `<message>` open tag ... I found it. Please do show the expect output, and actual output you're getting from your stylesheet.

Comment: Hello Larsh,
I have edited, the questions with input and expected output.

Comment: Your two listings of expected output contradict your both your stated requirements and the description that you give for the listings. The errors are too many to list, so lets just start with one: There is no `<error>` element in either output listing, in complete contradiction to your description. Please correct your question.

Comment: Your XML listings are an ugly mess that is hard to read. Please use a service like http://xmlprettyprint.com to make your listings readable.

Comment: I have updated my question to make it more understandable, also, I have pasted the work done by me so far.Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:o="http://www.origoservices.com"
                              exclude-result-prefixes="xsl o">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="ident">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="o:b_control[
    ((../../o:m_control/o:initiator_id='ASK') or (o:generic_quote_ind='Yes')) and
    (../o:application/o:tpsdata/o:service_type='QuickResponse') and
    (o:quote_or_print='Quote And Print')]">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  <error xmlns="http://www.origoservices.com">unable to provide quote</error> 
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="o:b_control[
    ((../../o:m_control/o:initiator_id='ASK') or (o:generic_quote_ind='Yes')) and
    (../o:application/o:tpsdata/o:service_type='QuickResponse') and
    (o:quote_or_print='Quote Only')]
    [not( o:generic_quote_ind)]">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  <generic_quote_ind xmlns="http://www.origoservices.com">Yes</generic_quote_ind> 
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```